# Why dont low density objects like nylon not fly into the air with more density?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density, buoyancy, unit-conversion

According to [this](http://www.dotmar.com.au/density.html) Website Nylon has a density between 1.11 to 1.18 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. Air on see level has a density of 1.225 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. So why does nylon not fly into the air like a helium balloon?

---

Sorry for this stupid question. I have to reduce my medication. It kills my brain.

Comment: Because air has a density of *$1.225Kg/m^3$* which is $0.001225g/cm^3$ - check your conversion.

Comment: Density of water $=1$ g cm$^{-3}$!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - your have your orders of magnitude wrong.

Air density is about 1.225 g / liter (which is a dm$^3$ if you were keeping score), or 1.225 mg/cm$^3$. So air is 1000 x less dense than nylon.

Answer (score -1):

Your air is denser than water (which has 1g/cm³) so why doesn't the Red Sea part and rise?

You need to fix your air density: you are off by about 3 orders of magnitude.